# Unpacking arguments from dict and list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
x = {'#33a02c': 1.8, '#5eb22d': 0.0, '#89c42e': 1.2}
```

and a list:

```
y = ['#33a02c', '#5eb22d', '#89c42e']
```

and I can get:

```
test = x[y[0]]
```

to get the value of the dictionary. How can I get use `*args` to create a function that unpacks my expressions? I have tried:

```
def my_function(*args):
   test= x[y[args]]
   return test
```

which is obviously not working as expected

Comment: Can you show example of how you would call the function and what the otuput is expected to be?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting a list of elements using the indexes passed in to the function, you can use list comprehension -

```
def my_function(*args):
   if len(args) == 0:
       return x[y[args[0]]]
   return [x[y[a]] for a in args]
```

Comment: This result in a list again. how can I return the results not as a list. for instance my_function(0) outputs [0.0]. I just want the result to be an item of the list. ie 0.0

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `operator.itemgetter()` from the `operator` module. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

If you want to do it yourself:

```
def my_function(*args):
   def extract_keys(dict_var):
      return [dict_var[key] for key in args]
   return extract_keys
```

Use as:

```
x = {'#33a02c': 1.8, '#5eb22d': 0.0, '#89c42e': 1.2}
y = ['#33a02c', '#5eb22d', '#89c42e']

print operator.itemgetter(*y)(x)
print my_function(*y)(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use *args here.  try this:

```
def myfunction(z):
    return [x[c] for c in z]
```

then you can iterate over the list it returns like this:

```
for q in myfunction(['#33a02c', '#5eb22d', '#89c42e']):
    print q
```

Comment: This only returns the first element. And you cannot call it with an arbitrary number of arguments.